# PyEnv BUILD FAILED installing Python on MacOS Ventura 13.2.1

Tags: xcode, homebrew, python-3.6, pyenv, slam

I'm working on a project from https://github.com/luigifreda/pyslam which uses only python 3.6.9, so I tried to install it:

```
pyenv install 3.6.9
```

and encountered a build failed:

```
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.6.9.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.9/Python-3.6.9.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.6.9...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 13.2.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/01/bx2q2rbn099ch5d1gr1zm5fc0000gn/T/python-build.20230216230654.91605
Results logged to /var/folders/01/bx2q2rbn099ch5d1gr1zm5fc0000gn/T/python-build.20230216230654.91605.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

MacOS Venture 13.2.1

Pyenv: 2.3.13
Home brew 4.0.1

Available python versions: 3.6.8

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling and followed the installation from https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#set-up-your-shell-environment-for-pyenv, but it's still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe this is the issue, https://github.com/luigifreda/pyslam/issues/88?

Comment: Why not just update the python version(https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aluigifreda%2Fpyslam%203.6.9&type=code) and see what happens?